# Performance testing on Azure Web App

Tags: performance, azure, testing

I am looking at few Performance testing features Azure Web Application has. I a following a tutorial given below. I tested a small application. My question is on how I can test an application where I have to login. My application users have to login to get to the home page. How will I do it? Can somone please help me on this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/app-service-web-app-performance-test?view=vsts

Comment: How about add an access token in the url you test?

Answer (score 1):

The load test you refer to is very limited. It supports only GET requests, so presumably it is meant for public pages. For more realistic scenarios you need to record (or build) test cases with navigation between multiple pages, where the login page is one and where state such as the login cookie/token is propagated between them.

Personally I work mostly with JMeter, see http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html on how to record a test. The recorded steps need to be edited before they can be used (hard-coded data replaced with variables). There is probably a similar tool from Microsoft, but the function in Azure portal seems overly simplistic.

In summary use another tool for more complex load testing, as the specified one handles only GET requests and can't do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I i will look into Jmeter.